# How to get/read text file from a url using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, webrequest, ashx

I'm trying to read text from URL:
https://whitworthpirates.com/services/schedule_txt.ashx?schedule=139

Here's my code:-

```
     var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(SourceUrl);

            var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            var content = response.GetResponseStream();
           
             using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
             {
                string strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Read: "+strContent+"<br />");
             }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write prints out nothing. I've tried the same code with https://google.com and StackOverflow webpages and it gets the text from these sites just fine.

I've also tried to download the file from the same URL using the following code:-

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(url, @"c:\myfile.txt");
```

It managed to download a .txt file on my server but it is an empty file with a size of 0KB.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that website requires you to send a `UserAgent` header. (Seems it can be anything)

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://whitworthpirates.com/services/schedule_txt.ashx?schedule=139");
webRequest.UserAgent = "Hej";

var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
var content = response.GetResponseStream();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
{
    string strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    strContent.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the response.

```cs
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

You also might need to tell that the response is plaintext so that the browser knows what to do with it.

```cs
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to include that in my source code (Just made the edits). I have that but it still doesn't work. It prints out nothing.

Comment: I've edited my response. If this is in a browser, you probably need to specify the content type.

Comment: It is still returning an empty string. Here's the URL that I'm trying to read from [link](https://whitworthpirates.com/services/schedule_txt.ashx?schedule=139)

Comment: Can you post the full class then?
If it doesn't fit here, perhaps in a Gist?